# Is moment.js available on a production server?

Tags: laravel, momentjs, forge

I have written some code that requires moment.js. It works on my local environment. Now i want to push this branch to production using laravel forge / and a git repository. I installed moment.js on my local environment using: npm install momentjs. My question is: will moment.js be available now on production server without me having to add 'npm install' to the laravel forge deployment script and adding momentjs to package.json. The reason i ask this also is because i read running 'npm install' in a deployment script is a no-no. So how do it do this properly?

Comment: *"[...] will moment.js be available now on production server without me having to add `npm install` to the laravel forge deployment script [...]"* - I doubt it. Not sure how forge works, but I doubt `node_modules` (which is where `npm install` installs the dependencies) will persist between environments; you generally need to run `npm install` on new code installations (like following a `git clone`, etc.). Where did you read that running `npm install` is a "no-no", and what was the rationale?

Comment: Thanks for your response Tim. To be honest your explanation sounds like the logical approach. The 'no-no' had something to do with the laravel forge deployment script timing out because npm install would take to long to run.

Comment: So how this works: You install moment.js through npm install moment,js...then before pushing to your remote repository  (which is linked to the digitalocean vps through laravel forge) you run : npm run dev (or npm run prod to optimize for production)..this compiles your javascripts (including moment.js) into app.js in public folder or whatever path you told it to use in webpack. Git picks up the changes in public/app.js. Then laravel forge takes over and pushes the changes to your digital ocean server.